# Angular: What is a good way to hide undefined attributes that exist in isolated scopes?

Tags: angularjs

I wanted to rewrite [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v83FK/1/) as it no longer worked in angular 1.2.1. From this exercise, I learned that a template is apparently always needed now in the isolated scopes.

somewhere in the directive:

```
           template: '<p>myAttr1 = {{myAttr1}} // Passed by my-attr1<br> 
                         myAttr2 = {{myAttr2}} // Passed by my-alias-attr2 <br>
                         myAttr3 = {{myAttr3}} // From controller
                      </p>',
```

I was not able,however, to successfully add this to the template:

```
 <p ng-show="myAttr4">myAttr4= {{myAttr4}} // Hidden and missing from attrs</p>
```

What is a good way to hide undefined attributes that are defined on the isolated scope but not given a value from the dom?

[my humble fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gogirl/gxd3k/)

EDIT: I use a directive called my-d1 to encapsulate the bootstrap tags. I use my-d2 to demo how to use  the @ in isolated scopes. 
[Working version merged with Sly's suggestions](http://jsfiddle.net/gogirl/MmXav/#base)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same template issue in Angular 1.2.0, see the first entry in the [1.2.0 breaking changes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-5):

> Child elements that are defined either in the application template or in some other directives template do not get the isolate scope. In theory, nobody should rely on this behavior, as it is very rare - in most cases the isolate directive has a template.

I'm not exactly sure what the issue is that you are encountering - it might be some incorrect markup or you are misnaming the scope variables listed in your isolate scope.

Using `ng-show` will correctly hide the element if the attribute has not been passed in.

i.e. your example here is correct: `<p ng-show="myAttr4">myAttr4= {{myAttr4}}</p>`

Updated version of your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly_cardinal/6paHM/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app='app'>
    <div class="dir" my-directive my-attr1="value one" my-attr3='value three'>
    </div>

    <div class="dir" my-directive my-attr1="value one" my-attr3='value three' my-attr4='value four'>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        //  can copy from $attrs into scope
        scope: {
            one: '@myAttr1',
            two: '@myAttr2',
            three: '@myAttr3'
        },

        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            // can copy from $attrs to controller
            $scope.four = $attrs.myAttr4 || 'Fourth value is missing';
        },

        template: '<p>myAttr1 = {{one}} // Passed by my-attr1</p> '+
                  '<p ng-show="two">myAttr2 = {{two}} // Passed by my-alias-attr2 </p>'+
                  '<p>myAttr3 = {{three}} // From controller</p>'+
                  '<p ng-show="four">myAttr4= {{four}} // Has a value and is shown</p>'
    }
});
```